# Ambari cluster : Host registration failed

Tags: ssh, hortonworks-data-platform, ambari

I am setting up an ambari cluster with 3 virtualbox VMs running Ubuntu 16.04LTS.

I followed this [hortonworks tutorial](https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.5.0.3/bk_ambari-installation/content/ch_Getting_Ready.html).

However when I am going to create a cluster using Ambari Cluster Install Wizard I get the below error during the step 3 - "Confirm Hosts".

```
26 Jun 2017 16:41:11,553  WARN [Thread-34] BSRunner:292 - Bootstrap process timed out. It will be destroyed.
26 Jun 2017 16:41:11,554  INFO [Thread-34] BSRunner:309 - Script log Mesg

INFO:root:BootStrapping hosts ['thanuja.ambari-agent1.com', 'thanuja.ambari-agent2.com'] using /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ambari_server cluster primary OS: ubuntu16 with user 'thanuja'with ssh Port '22' sshKey File /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/5/sshKey password File null using tmp dir /var/run/ambari-server/bootstrap/5 ambari: thanuja.ambari-server.com; server_port: 8080; ambari version: 2.5.0.3; user_run_as: root
INFO:root:Executing parallel bootstrap


 Bootstrap process timed out. It was destroyed.
```

I have read number of posts saying that this is related to not enabling Password-less SSH to the hosts. But I can ssh to the hosts without password from the server.

I am running ambari as non-root user with root privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [post](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/104595/ambari-automatic-registration-failed-step-3-confir.html) helped me.

I modified the users in host machines so that they can execute sudo commands without password using `visudo` command.

Please post if you have any alternative answers.

Comment: that is a correct way.
See also https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.4.0.0/bk_ambari-security/content/sudoer_configuration_agent.html